# jquery function (.on) not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

Ive got some problem with my jquery function. First of all, this is my HTML head

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/datepicker.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.js" type= 'text/javascript'></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-tooltip.js" type= 'text/javascript'></script>

    <script src="js/buttons.js"></script>
```

and here is the code from my button.js file

```
$(window).load(
    function(){
        ...
        $(document).on('click', '.popover a', function(){
            alert("asd");
        });

        $('#button_nowtime').popover({
            trigger: 'click',
            html: 'true',
            title:  "<b>Čas</b>",
            content: 
            function() {
                var returnstring="",button;
                    for(var i=0; i<files.length; i++){
                        button = document.createElement("a");  
                        button.innerText = "someText"
                        button.href="#";
                        returnstring+=button.outerHTML;
                    }
                return returnstring;
            }
        });
   }
);
```

html

```
<a href="#" id="button_nowtime" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="popover" title="" >N/A</a>
```

the problem is, the alert("asd") wont pop up when I click on any button in the tooltip

Comment: Please don't mix jQuery and native DOM methods (createElement etc.)

Comment: what is your jQuery version ? version < 1.7 won't have `.on()`

Comment: @ShivanRaptor It's the latest one : `1.10.2` (direct link to http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js )

Comment: seems fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/P3e8b/1/

Comment: @ThiefMaster Is it a personal preference or bad practice ? (Since jquery is a javascript library, yes i m stating the obvious, i don't see why not)

Comment: I have added the HTML code (sorry I have forgotten it)

Comment: @Aurun P Johny, this is interesting, when I add /show to the fidle and copy the code to some my test.html it wont work :/

Comment: then your jquery version is not supporting

Comment: but I have copied the whole code without changing anything, means that I have also copied the same jQuery file

Comment: @PatsyIssa mixing them is not a good practice. jQuery adds extra functions on selectors. See this (make sure you open browser's console to view the result): http://jsfiddle.net/X4vPf/

Answer (score 1):

You should use $.ready instead of window.load, probabily your code doesn't work because window.load occurs before your objects exist. http://www.dotnetbull.com/2013/08/document-ready-vs-window-onload.html

This sample works http://jsfiddle.net/nWKqt/

`[ignore this - just including a code block so stackoverflow will let me post the above JSFiddle link. Yeah, seriously.]`

Also, you wrote a code that depends on a class that is defined not by you but from a jquery plugin, which you fire after you declared the events.

Try to put the click event after you declared the popover plugin, but better would be to define your cssClass and depend on it.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont use this:

```
 $(".popover a").click( function(){
            alert("asd");
        });
```

the old method works fine ..